# table not contained / resized correctly using jquery-resize plugin

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, flexbox

I am using the [jquery-resize](https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable) plugin with two DIV panels.
I have forked the [codepen to demonstrate](https://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/Yreded) the problem.

The table contained in the left panel is not resized with the parent, even though the size is set to 100%.

```css
/*THE TABLE WIDTH SHOULD BE 100% OF THE PARENT.*/

table {
  width: 80%
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-container">

  <div class="panel-left">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="splitter">
  </div>

  <div class="panel-right">
    right panel
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add `table-layout: fixed;` to your table style: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzvGrX

Comment: fixed layout seems to work, but it has the aweful caveat that the columns are now all sized the same. I would prefer the columns to be calculated correctly, and the table fit. Is there no way to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with tables. You can play with the proportions, and `word-break`, but nothing more I believe: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzvGrX

Comment: For me this work as it suppose to, and as soon as the space in left panel becomes positive (big enough to fit the table) it stretch to be 100% wide. How do you mean it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Do you expect the table to shrink to fit the panel? ... If yes, a table cell can't be smaller than its content unless you either make it `table-layout: fixed` or wrap the content in the cell and give it a max width (well, you can make the table row/cell Flexbox elements, though then they stop being table elements and you loose those features).

Comment: I will use fixed layout - I need the table to size with the panel - I don’t mind if the cells are wrapped - I.e 2 lines or more per cell.